# Kubernetes - connect to cassandra from job to different pod

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra, cqlsh

When I'm trying to execute the following command

```
["/bin/sh", "-c", "cqlsh cassandra.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local -f /path/to/schema.cql"]
```

from my Job, I am receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 2443, in <module>
    main(*read_options(sys.argv[1:], os.environ))
  File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 2421, in main
    encoding=options.encoding)
  File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 485, in __init__
    load_balancing_policy=WhiteListRoundRobinPolicy([self.hostname]),
  File "/usr/share/cassandra/lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.11.0-bb96859b.zip/cassandra-driver-3.11.0-bb96859b/cassandra/policies.py", line 417, in __init__
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

My Job is defined as Helm Hook with `post-install` annotation. My Cassandra Pod is defined using StatefulSet.

```
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: cassandra
spec:
  serviceName: cassandra
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cassandra
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: cassandra
          image: cassandra:3
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 7000
              name: intra-node
            - containerPort: 7001
              name: tls-intra-node
            - containerPort: 7199
              name: jmx
            - containerPort: 9042
              name: cql
          env:
            - name: CASSANDRA_SEEDS
              value: cassandra-0.cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local
            - name: MAX_HEAP_SIZE
              value: 256M
            - name: HEAP_NEWSIZE
              value: 100M
            - name: CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME
              value: "Cassandra"
            - name: CASSANDRA_DC
              value: "DC1"
            - name: CASSANDRA_RACK
              value: "Rack1"
            - name: CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH
              value: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
          volumeMounts:
            - name: cassandra-data
              mountPath: /var/lib/cassandra/data
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: cassandra-data
        annotations:  # comment line if you want to use a StorageClass
          # or specify which StorageClass
          volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: ""   # comment line if you
          # want to use a StorageClass or specify which StorageClass
      spec:
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
```

And this is my Service:

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: cassandra
  name: cassandra
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - port: 9042
  selector
    app: cassandra
```

When I run the `cqlsh` command manually from the container, everything works. Unfortunately, the automated solution throws the mentioned error.

Am I missing something in the Service configuration? I have thought since I am connecting to service from the Pod created by Job, it should work.

EDIT:
Job looks like this:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: init-db
spec:
  template:
    metadata: 
      name: init-db
      annotations: 
        "helm.sh/hooks": postn-install
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: cqlsh
        image: <cassandra-image>
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "cqlsh cassandra.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local -f /path/to/schema.cql"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: cass-init
          mountPath: /etc/config
    volumes:
      ...
```

And here is the output of `etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndtos:5
```

Comment: Can you share the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` from the job pod?

Comment: I cannot enter the container since it had crushed

Comment: you can just execute cat `/etc/resolv.conf` as a command to see the content

Comment: how does your post install job looks like , please share the snippet.

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I've added the resolv.conf and job yaml

Comment: your cassandra is in default namespace so ypu should use something like `cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: @TarunKhosla unfortunately it is not working, same error. We are using Istio, maybe it causes problems?

Comment: I donot think istio is causing this.

Comment: does my-namespace has any service for Cassandra? You are trying to execute cassandra.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local which means you are trying to look for Cassandra on my-namespace.  If you can update the Cassandra statefulset and service to contain `namespace: my-namespace` under metadata then your command `"/bin/sh", "-c", "cqlsh cassandra.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local -f /path/to/schema.cql"` will make sense.

Comment: What type of service is it? ClusterIP or Headless? The deployment and service are collocated in same namespace?

Comment: @MilanBaran it is ClusterIP. Yes, both of them are in the same namespace.

Comment: Are you running some service mesh like istio?

Comment: @ChristophRaab yes, I have istio.

Comment: Anything new on the topic? Did you have a change to check my considerations regarding istio in my answer below?

Answer (score 2):

The error you posted indicates that wherever you're running the cqlsh command, it cannot resolve the service name.

Depending on how your k8s cluster is configured and where the job runs (inside the same k8s cluster or external), you'll need to expose access to the pods with `Ingress` or `NodePort`.

Aleš Nosek has a good explanation of how to access pods in [his blog post here](http://alesnosek.com/blog/2017/02/14/accessing-kubernetes-pods-from-outside-of-the-cluster/). Cheers!

Comment: I think it runs in the same cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running insto as service mesh, there might be some problems with your setup.

First I would recommend enabling envoy logging for both pods:

`kubectl exec -it <pod-name> -c istio-proxy -- curl -X POST http://localhost:15000/logging?level=trace`

No, follow the istio sidecar logs by

`kubectl logs <pod-name> -c isiot-proxy -f`

This might already give you some information, why the connection is failing.

Some ideas what might be the problem:

1. The cassandra's pod doesn't have a sidecar

If the cassandra pod doesn't have a sidecar and you are enforcing mTLS, it will receive encrypted traffic, but is unable to decrypt it. This contradicts the documentation and seems to be a bug. You can disable mTLS for traffic to the cassandra service with a DestinationRule:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: cassandra-disable-mtls
spec:
  host: "cassandra-host" #insert correct cassandra name here
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: DISABLE
```

2. The job's pod doesn't have a sidecar

If the cassandra pod has a sidecar, but the job's pod doesn't and you enforce mTLS, the cassandras sidecar will deny access, since traffic isn't encrypted. You can either inject a sidecar into the job's pod (recommended) or enable `PERMISSIVE` mode for cassandra, so the sidecar will accept both ssl encrypted and plain text traffic.

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: PeerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: cassandra-allow-plain-traffic
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cassandra
  mtls:
    mode: PERMISSIVE
```

Please let me know if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The statefulset doesn't have a selector so the YAML in question doesn't work. If you use the below YAML s it works and connects to the job as well. Everything will be deployed in default namespace. You need to use appropriate storage class (below example uses standard)
You can follow cassandra deployment from [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/cassandra/)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: cassandra
spec:
  serviceName: cassandra
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cassandra
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cassandra
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: cassandra
          image: cassandra:3
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 7000
              name: intra-node
            - containerPort: 7001
              name: tls-intra-node
            - containerPort: 7199
              name: jmx
            - containerPort: 9042
              name: cql
          env:
            - name: CASSANDRA_SEEDS
              value: cassandra-0.cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local
            - name: MAX_HEAP_SIZE
              value: 256M
            - name: HEAP_NEWSIZE
              value: 100M
            - name: CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME
              value: "Cassandra"
            - name: CASSANDRA_DC
              value: "DC1"
            - name: CASSANDRA_RACK
              value: "Rack1"
            - name: CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH
              value: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
          volumeMounts:
            - name: cassandra-data
              mountPath: /var/lib/cassandra/data
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: cassandra-data
      spec:
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
        storageClassName: standard
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
```

The service YAML

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: cassandra
  name: cassandra
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 9042
  selector:
    app: cassandra
```

The Job YAML , The command has been modified to describe cluster as it connects and prints the required cluster info.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: init-db
spec:
  template:
    metadata: 
      name: init-db
      annotations: 
        "helm.sh/hooks": postn-install
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
      - name: cqlsh
        image: cassandra:3
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "cqlsh cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local 9042 -e 'describe cluster'"]
```

Comment: I have added this, however, it still does not work.

Comment: what is the error that you get ? because it works perfectly fine for me.